# Overfull hbox in toc

Tags: table-of-contents, titletoc

While compiling the code:

```
\documentclass[draft]{book}
% ---------------------------------------------
\usepackage{titletoc}
\contentsmargin{0pt}
\titlecontents{chapter}[0pc]%
{\addvspace{2.7ex}\fontsize{14}{14}\selectfont}%
{\contentslabel[\thecontentslabel]{0pc}\hspace{1pc}}%
{}%
{\nolinebreak\hfill\thecontentspage}
% ---------------------------------------------
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{A chapter}
\end{document}
```

I get the warning:

```
Overfull \hbox (7.04991pt too wide) detected at line 1
```

What should I change to remove the warning?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `0pc` there is not enough room for the chapter number. For the MWE `7.1pt` seems to be enough to accommodate the `1`, in your real document, the required space may be larger.

```
\documentclass[draft]{book}
% ---------------------------------------------
\usepackage{titletoc}
\contentsmargin{0pt}
\titlecontents{chapter}[7.1pt]% <------------------------- change here
{\addvspace{2.7ex}\fontsize{14}{14}\selectfont}%
{\contentslabel[\thecontentslabel]{7.1pt}\hspace{1pc}}% <- and here
{}%
{\nolinebreak\hfill\thecontentspage}
% ---------------------------------------------
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{A chapter}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have a solution with  `\contentspush`:

```
\documentclass[draft]{book}
% ---------------------------------------------
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage{calc}
\contentsmargin{0pt}
\titlecontents{chapter}[0pt]%
{\addvspace{2.7ex}\fontsize{14}{14}\selectfont
}%
{\contentspush{\phantom{11}}\contentslabel[\hfill\thecontentslabel]{2em}\hspace{1pc}}%
{}%
{\nolinebreak\hfill\thecontentspage}
% ---------------------------------------------
\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\chapter{A First Chapter}
\setcounter{chapter}9
\chapter{Another Chapter}

\end{document}
```

[image]